# Cycle through ical array using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, icalendar

I am having trouble figuring out how to cycle through an array created from a Google Calendar iCal. I don't know if I am searching for the right thing as I can't seem to find any answers for this issue as I search for 'php cycle ical array' as well as other similar variants. I would like to use a foreach loop but it keeps including the headers of the Google Calendar. This is the result I keep getting

```
-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
2.0
GREGORIAN
PUBLISH
Faith Lutheran Church
America/Anchorage
Faith Lutheran Church in Anchorage, Alaska is a congregation of Bible-believing Lutheran Christians. Please join us for worship on Sunday mornings at 10:30 AM. Faith offers quality Christian elementary school (K-8) and preschool (3 & 4 yr olds) education. We are a proud member of the Wisconsin Evangelical Lutheran Synod.
Array
Array
```

when using

```
$file1 = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/i8j5d94tpgnnqu6h8q3mt6uc48%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics";
include('../assets/includes/iCalEasyReader.php');
$ical = new iCalEasyReader();
$lines = $ical->load(file_get_contents($file1));

foreach($lines as $event){
echo $event."<br>";
}
```

Here is iCalEasyReader.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * iCalEasyReader is an easy to understood class, loads a "ics" format string and returns an array with the traditional iCal fields
 *
 * @category    Parser
 * @author      Matias Perrone <matias.perrone at gmail dot com>
 * @author      Timo Henke <phpstuff@thenke.de> (Some ideas taken partially from iCalParse on http://www.phpclasses.org/)
 * @license     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 * @version     1.4.1
 * @param   string  $data   ics file string content
 * @param   array|false $data $makeItEasy   the idea is to convert this "keys" into the "values", converting the DATE and DATE-TIME values to the respective DateTime type of PHP, also all the keys are lowercased
 * @return  array|false
 */
class iCalEasyReader
{
    private $ical = null;
    private $_lastitem = null;

    public function &load($data)
    {
        $this->ical = false;
        $regex_opt = 'mib';

        // Lines in the string
        $lines = mb_split( '[\r\n]+', $data );

        // Delete empty ones
        $last = count( $lines );
        for($i = 0; $i < $last; $i ++)
        {
            if (trim( $lines[$i] ) == '')
                unset( $lines[$i] );
        }
        $lines = array_values( $lines );

        // First and last items
        $first = 0;
        $last = count( $lines ) - 1;

        if (! ( mb_ereg_match( '^BEGIN:VCALENDAR', $lines[$first], $regex_opt ) and mb_ereg_match( '^END:VCALENDAR', $lines[$last], $regex_opt ) ))
        {
            $first = null;
            $last = null;
            foreach ( $lines as $i => &$line )
            {
                if (mb_ereg_match( '^BEGIN:VCALENDAR', $line, $regex_opt ))
                    $first = $i;

                if (mb_ereg_match( '^END:VCALENDAR', $line, $regex_opt ))
                {
                    $last = $i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Procesing
        if (! is_null( $first ) and ! is_null( $last ))
        {
            $lines = array_slice( $lines, $first + 1, ( $last - $first - 1 ), true );

            $group = null;
            $parentgroup = null;
            $this->ical = [];
            $addTo = [];
            $addToElement = null;
            foreach ( $lines as $line )
            {
                $clave = null;
                $pattern = '^(BEGIN|END)\:(.+)$'; // (VALARM|VTODO|VJOURNAL|VEVENT|VFREEBUSY|VCALENDAR|DAYLIGHT|VTIMEZONE|STANDARD)
                mb_ereg_search_init( $line );
                $regs = mb_ereg_search_regs( $pattern, $regex_opt );
                if ($regs)
                {
                    // $regs
                    // 0 => BEGIN:VEVENT
                    // 1 => BEGIN
                    // 2 => VEVENT
                    switch ( $regs[1] )
                    {
                        case 'BEGIN' :
                            if (! is_null( $group ))
                                $parentgroup = $group;

                            $group = trim( $regs[2] );

                            // Adding new values to groups
                            if (is_null( $parentgroup ))
                            {
                                if (! array_key_exists( $group, $this->ical ))
                                    $this->ical[$group] = [null];
                                else
                                    $this->ical[$group][] = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (! array_key_exists( $parentgroup, $this->ical ))
                                    $this->ical[$parentgroup] = [$group => [null]];

                                if (! array_key_exists( $group, $this->ical[$parentgroup] ))
                                    $this->ical[$parentgroup][$group] = [null];
                                else
                                    $this->ical[$parentgroup][$group][] = null;
                            }

                            break;
                        case 'END' :
                            if (is_null( $group ))
                                $parentgroup = null;

                            $group = null;
                            break;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (! in_array( $line[0], [" ", "\t"] ))
                    $this->addItem( $line, $group, $parentgroup );
                else
                    $this->concatItem( $line );
            }
        }

        return $this->ical;
    }

    public function addType(&$value, $item)
    {
        $type = explode( '=', $item );

        if (count( $type ) > 1 and $type[0] == 'VALUE')
            $value['type'] = $type[1];
        else
            $value[$type[0]] = $type[1];

        return $value;
    }

    public function addItem($line, $group, $parentgroup)
    {
        $line = $this->transformLine( $line );
        $item = explode( ':', $line, 2 );
        // If $group is null is an independent value
        if (is_null( $group ))
        {
            $this->ical[$item[0]] = ( count( $item ) > 1 ? $item[1] : null );
            $this->_lastitem = &$this->ical[$item[0]];
        }
        // If $group is set then is an item of a group
        else
        {
            $subitem = explode( ';', $item[0], 2 );
            if (count( $subitem ) == 1)
                $value = ( count( $item ) > 1 ? $item[1] : null );
            else
            {
                $value = ['value' => $item[1]];
                $this->addType( $value, $subitem[1] );
            }

            // Multi value
            if (is_string( $value ))
            {
                $z = explode( ';', $value );
                if (count( $z ) > 1)
                {
                    $value = [];
                    foreach ( $z as &$v )
                    {
                        $t = explode( '=', $v );
                        $value[$t[0]] = $t[count( $t ) - 1];
                    }
                }
                unset( $z );
            }

            if (is_null( $parentgroup ))
            {
                $this->ical[$group][count( $this->ical[$group] ) - 1][$subitem[0]] = $value;
                $this->_lastitem = &$this->ical[$group][count( $this->ical[$group] ) - 1][$subitem[0]];
            }
            else
            {
                $this->ical[$parentgroup][$group][count( $this->ical[$parentgroup][$group] ) - 1][$subitem[0]] = $value;
                $this->_lastitem = &$this->ical[$parentgroup][$group][count( $this->ical[$parentgroup][$group] ) - 1][$subitem[0]];
            }
        }
    }

    public function concatItem($line)
    {
        $line = mb_substr( $line, 1 );
        if (is_array( $this->_lastitem ))
        {
            $line = $this->transformLine( $this->_lastitem['value'] . $line );
            $this->_lastitem['value'] = $line;
        }
        else
        {
            $line = $this->transformLine( $this->_lastitem . $line );
            $this->_lastitem = $line;
        }
    }

    public function transformLine($line)
    {
        $patterns = ['\\\\[n]', '\\\\[t]', '\\\\,', '\\\\;'];
        $replacements = ["\n", "\t", ",", ";"];

        return $this->mb_eregi_replace_all( $patterns, $replacements, $line );
    }

    public function mb_eregi_replace_all($pattern, $replacement, $string)
    {
        if (is_array( $pattern ) and is_array( $replacement ))
        {
            foreach ( $pattern as $i => $patron )
            {
                if (array_key_exists( $i, $replacement ))
                    $reemplazo = $replacement[$i];
                else
                    $reemplazo = '';

                $string = mb_eregi_replace( $patron, $reemplazo, $string );
            }
        }
        elseif (is_string( $pattern ) and is_string( $replacement ))
            $string = mb_eregi_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );

        return $string;
    }
}
```

I want to cycle through the VEVENT entries of the array seen below.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Faith Lutheran Church
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Anchorage
X-WR-CALDESC:Faith Lutheran Church in Anchorage\, Alaska is a congregation 
 of Bible-believing Lutheran Christians. Please join us for worship on Sunda
 y mornings at 10:30 AM. Faith offers quality Christian elementary school (K
 -8) and preschool (3 & 4 yr olds) education. We are a proud member of the W
 isconsin Evangelical Lutheran Synod.
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Anchorage
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Anchorage
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0900
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:AKDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0900
TZNAME:AKST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190313T020000Z
DTEND:20190313T030000Z
DTSTAMP:20190303T061701Z
UID:2be6h1ru67cg0os886g0dqgjc5@google.com
CREATED:20190228T205014Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20190228T205015Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Tuesday Teen Night
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190303T203000Z
DTEND:20190303T210000Z
DTSTAMP:20190303T061701Z
UID:1kj37lnrqcbefunj0mmsktajsf@google.com
CREATED:20190227T173557Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20190227T173557Z
LOCATION:Faith Lutheran Church\, 5200 Lake Otis Pkwy\, Anchorage\, AK 99507
 \, USA
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Congregation Call Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190316T230000Z
DTEND:20190317T010000Z
DTSTAMP:20190303T061701Z
UID:0bl4hkd2ogjplurldf59mihpen@google.com
CREATED:20190227T173218Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20190227T173218Z
LOCATION:Faith Lutheran Church\, 5200 Lake Otis Pkwy\, Anchorage\, AK 99507
 \, USA
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Trivia Contest Fellowship Event
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

I'm not very familiar with arrays which is why I am stuck. I checked out several tutorials about php arrays including w3schools.com but I just don't understand why it keeps returning the headers and not the events.

Comment: it may be more useful to include the keys if any `foreach($lines as $key=>$event){`  If they have keys (which I don't know) then you could do `if($key == 'header') continue;` etc...  the keyword continue skips the rest of the loop and goes to the next item.  The key is like `['key'=>'value']` part of an array.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thank you for the suggestion but it didn't solve my problem. I am adding the start of the iCal file above to show what I am trying to loop through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying several different things I have found a solution. You need to set the sub array in the foreach statement by using the sub array name in brackets immediately following the base array variable like the following:

```
foreach($lines['VEVENT'] as $event){
  CODE TO PERFORM HERE
}
```

I hope this helps anyone searching for a solution to this.